# Why does the inclusion of a .Dim attribute cause d_ply to fail?

Tags: r, plyr

Why does the inclusion of a .Dim attribute cause d_ply to fail?

```
library(plyr)

dt <- structure(
    c(946771200, 947376000, 947980800)
    ,.Dim = 3L # FIXME: including the .Dim attribute will cause d_ply to fail
    ,class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt")
    ,tzone = "")

myDF <- data.frame( 
    dt = dt
    ,dat = seq(1:3))
#attr( myDF$dt, "dim" ) <- NULL # FIXME: removing the .Dim attribute will make d_ply work again
attr( myDF$dt, "dim" )

d_ply( .data = myDF, .variables = .(dt), .fun = show )
```

returns

```
Error in attributes(out) <- attributes(col) : 
  dims [product 3] do not match the length of object [1]
```

`myDF` and `str(myDF)` look completely fine to the eye.  When I tried to create a reproducible example, I started with:

```
myDF <- data.frame(
    dt = as.POSIXct( c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-08", "2000-01-15") ) 
    ,dat = seq(1:3)
    ) 
d_ply( .data = myDF, .variables = .(dt), .fun = show )
```

... which works just fine.  I had to `dput` (or `attr`) my dataset before I found that `.Dim` attribute.

The reason I'm looking at this is because I have a function that aggregates each date by week and returns a vector including this '.Dim' attribute.

```
dt <- c( 
    seq( as.POSIXct( '2001-01-01'), by = '5 days', length.out = 52 ))    
weekCutoffPoints <- cut( dt, breaks ="week", labels = FALSE )    
endpoints <- 
    # R Inferno 8.3.22: "by is for data frames", but I get the same result with tapply
    #tapply( X = dt, INDEX = weekCutoffPoints, FUN = max )
    by( data = dt, INDICES = weekCutoffPoints, FUN = max )    
dt <- as.POSIXct( 
    endpoints[ rownames(endpoints)[weekCutoffPoints] ]
    , origin = as.POSIXct('1970-1-1') )

# now try to use these dates in the same simple d_plyr call
myDF <- data.frame( 
    dt = dt
    ,dat = seq(1:52))
#attr( myDF$dt, "dim" ) <- NULL # FIXME: removing the .Dim attribute will make d_ply work again
attr( myDF$dt, "dim" )

d_ply( .data = myDF, .variables = .(dt), .fun = show )
```

Bonus points: This `cut`/`by` works for me, but is my actual problem this way I use to align dates within the same week?

Thanks, guys!

Comment: d_ply expects data frame and they need Dims of length 2.

Comment: In the first example, the argument to d_ply is myDF, which is a two dimensional data.frame.  `dim(myDF)` returns 3 2.  `class(myDF)` returns "data.frame".